# Bootstrap accordion table is not working on Laravel project

Tags: css, laravel

I'm creating a Project with Laravel Breeze template, I know that Breeze is using tailwinds css, but I want to try to copy and paste to see if this collapsible table works using bootstrap in [codepen](https://codepen.io/giovanipires/pen/yZWZbq) to my views, also I have added bootstrap CDN to the app.blade.php:

`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">`

and

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous">`

and it works, but only the styling of the table, but the collapsible/accordion is not working unlike the sample code in that codepen above, i don't know why.